# Java client for .Net WCF service

Tags: java, .net, wcf, client-server

Have you ever heard or had such experience? Are there any known issues in such a scenario, that does not exist in .Net client scenario. I guess development in such a scenario will not be as smooth as in .Net client. Share your experience please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, entirely smooth. You are just restricted in terms of what bindings you can use - for instance, netTcp binding won't work. But the interoperable ones like the HTTP bindings should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a Java Client but then you should only use interoperable features of WCF
Have a look at this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730017.aspx